# Updating the ControlSource of a WebBrowserControl in Access sets the value of some Combo Boxes to null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an Access 2016 database that stores a very large list of parts. On a form, the user can select options to mark a part as in stock, among other things.

[image: Screenshot of combo box options]

Here I have 3 combo boxes. The first allows the user to select a batch - this has no impact on the part selection, it will be used to record where the part came from.  Second is part category. Updating it triggers a refresh on the part type to filter the database for that specific category.

Updating the third combo box triggers a WebBrowserControl to change its SourceControl to display the image of that part. (There are tens of thousands of potential parts - I don't want to package their images with the db and thumbnails are available on the web)

It works, but the weird thing is that doing so resets the 2nd and 3rd combo box to null. That kinda messes up me getting that data into the database later.  I can't figure out why.  Here's the AfterUpdate code for cb 2 & 3:

```
Private Sub ChooseCatName_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ChoosePartType = ""
    Me.ChoosePartType.Requery
    Me.ChoosePartNum = ""
    Me.wb_partImg.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub ChoosePartType_AfterUpdate()
    imgUrl = getImgUrl(Me.ChoosePartType)
    If imgUrl = "" Then
        Me.wb_partImg.Visible = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    imgUrl = imgUrl & "/85x85p." & Right(imgUrl, 3)
    Me.wb_partImg.ControlSource = "=""" & imgUrl & """"
    Me.wb_partImg.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Note: getImgUrl just returns a string - the url based on the part number

So - why would ChooseCatName and ChoosePartType change to null as soon as the wb_partImg.ControlSource is changed??

Comment: I get same behavior. Is first combobox not set to Null? Only solution may be to set global variables or TempVars then re-populate comboboxes.

Comment: Well, I tried again. Built another form. Comboboxes are not set to Null. Try deleting and recreating comboboxes.